# Stacked with C assignment

Tags: c, string, function

I had to write a function `int bit_to_ascii(const char input[], char output[]);` that reads from array of characters binary code and than translates it. And I already did that.

Everything works fine while I am using Code::Blocks on my home computer. But when I am putting code on the server where I have to keep program for marks, it's compiling but gives me a segmentation fault after the first step of the program. What can be my fault? And what is the difference between the compiler in Code::Blocks and on the server?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINES 5

/* assignment #1 function prototype */
int bit_to_ascii(const char input[], char output[]);

int main( ) {

const char *core_data[ ] = {
"0", /* should insert the null byte '\0' only */

"01010111 This sequence contains the letter 'W'       " /*  87 = 'W' */
"      r5 0 #! 1 1 gP 0 f66-:] 0 [ } 1 v4t^ 0 1 n>?:77" /* 101 = 'e' */
" junk ^*@&#^% 0110  more junk }{r;,<> 1100         2x" /* 108 = 'l' */
"                  0    1       1     0 0          011" /*  99 = 'c' */
"0  ^%jh  1 ]{) OVR 1 - 0 _! 9 + 1  118Y z(x pM1      " /* 111 = 'o' */
"This next group of 8 should be SKP skipped! 11111111 " /* skipped */
"*&^! 0  1  1  0 1     1 0     128673kjshd:L<    2938 " /* 109 = 'm' */
"      r5 0 #! 1 1 gP 0 f66-:] 0 [ } 1 v4t^ 0 1 n>?:77" /* 101 = 'e' */
"#!/bin/bash 00  1 00 00 0 g^b-ps 6@&^%               " /*  32 = ' ' */
"01010100 This sequence contains the letter 'T'       " /*  84 = 'T' */
"0  ^%jh  1 ]{) OVR 1 - 0 _! 9 + 1  118Y z(x pM1      " /* 111 = 'o' */
"#!/bin/bash 00  1 00 00 0 g^b-ps 6@&^%               " /*  32 = ' ' */
"---repeat--->0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1<------------RPT2--------" /*  79 = 'O' */
"0 1 0 1 0bbavac9872962  000&*************************" /*  80 = 'P' */
"a0b0c1d1e0f0g1h0ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*******************" /*  50 = '2' */
"00fg333                                110100>>>>>>>>" /*  52 = '4' */
"00fg333                                110100>>>>>>>>" /*  52 = '4' */
"                     0000                            ",/*  0 = '\0' */

"00011110 This char should not be inserted!           " /*  30 cntrl */
" 00011111 This char should not be inserted!          " /*  31 cntrl */
"  00100000                                           " /*  32 = ' ' */
"   00100001                                          " /*  33 = '!' */
"    00100010                                         " /*  34 = '"' */
"     00100011                                        " /*  35 = '#' */
"      00100100                                       " /*  36 = '$' */
"       00100101                                      " /*  37 = '%' */
"        00100110                                     " /*  38 = '&' */
"         00100111                                    " /*  39 = ''' */
"          00101000                                   " /*  40 = '(' */
"           00101001                                  " /*  41 = ')' */
"            00101010                                 " /*  42 = '*' */
"             00101011                                " /*  43 = '+' */
"              00101100                               " /*  44 = ',' */
"               00101101                              " /*  45 = '-' */
"                00101110                             " /*  46 = '.' */
"                 00101111                            " /*  47 = '/' */
"                  00110000                           " /*  48 = '0' */
"                   00110001                          " /*  49 = '1' */
"                    00110010                         " /*  50 = '2' */
"                     00110011                        " /*  51 = '3' */
"                      00110100                       " /*  52 = '4' */
"                       00110101                      " /*  53 = '5' */
"                        00110110                     " /*  54 = '6' */
"                         00110111                    " /*  55 = '7' */
"                          00111000                   " /*  56 = '8' */
"                           00111001                  " /*  57 = '9' */
"                            00111010                 " /*  58 = ':' */
"                             00111011                " /*  59 = ';' */
"                              00111100               " /*  60 = '<' */
"                               00111101              " /*  61 = '=' */
"                                00111110             " /*  62 = '>' */
"                                 00111111            " /*  63 = '?' */
"                                  01000000           " /*  64 = '@' */
"                                   00000000          ",/*   0 = '\0'*/

"                                    01000001         " /*  65 = 'A' */
"                                     01000010        " /*  66 = 'B' */
"                                      01000011       " /*  67 = 'C' */
"                                       01000100      " /*  68 = 'D' */
"                                        01000101     " /*  69 = 'E' */
"                                         01000110    " /*  70 = 'F' */
"                                          01000111   " /*  71 = 'G' */
"                                           01001000  " /*  72 = 'H' */
"                                            01001001 " /*  73 = 'I' */
"                                             01001010" /*  74 = 'J' */
"                                            01001011 " /*  75 = 'K' */
"                                           01001100  " /*  76 = 'L' */
"                                          01001101   " /*  77 = 'M' */
"                                         01001110    " /*  78 = 'N' */
"                                        01001111     " /*  79 = 'O' */
"                                       01010000      " /*  80 = 'P' */
"                                      01010001       " /*  81 = 'Q' */
"                                     01010010        " /*  82 = 'R' */
"                                    01010011         " /*  83 = 'S' */
"                                   01010100          " /*  84 = 'T' */
"                                  01010101           " /*  85 = 'U' */
"                                 01010110            " /*  86 = 'V' */
"                                01010111             " /*  87 = 'W' */
"                               01011000              " /*  88 = 'X' */
"                              01011001               " /*  89 = 'Y' */
"                             01011010                " /*  90 = 'Z' */
"                            01011011                 " /*  91 = '[' */
"                           01011100                  " /*  92 = '/' */
"                          01011101                   " /*  93 = ']' */
"                         01011110                    " /*  94 = '^' */
"                        01011111                     " /*  95 = '_' */
"                       01100000                      " /*  96 = '`' */
"                      00000000                       ",/*   0 = '\0'*/

"                     01100001                        " /*  97 = 'a' */
"                    01100010                         " /*  98 = 'b' */
"                   01100011                          " /*  99 = 'c' */
"                  01100100                           " /* 100 = 'd' */
"                 01100101                            " /* 101 = 'e' */
"                01100110                             " /* 102 = 'f' */
"               01100111                              " /* 103 = 'g' */
"              01101000                               " /* 104 = 'h' */
"             01101001                                " /* 105 = 'i' */
"            01101010                                 " /* 106 = 'j' */
"           01101011                                  " /* 107 = 'k' */
"          01101100                                   " /* 108 = 'l' */
"         01101101                                    " /* 109 = 'm' */
"        01101110                                     " /* 110 = 'n' */
"       01101111                                      " /* 111 = 'o' */
"      01110000                                       " /* 112 = 'p' */
"     01110001                                        " /* 113 = 'q' */
"    01110010                                         " /* 114 = 'r' */
"   01110011                                          " /* 115 = 's' */
"  01110100                                           " /* 116 = 't' */
" 01110101                                            " /* 117 = 'u' */
"01110110                                             " /* 118 = 'v' */
" 01110111                                            " /* 119 = 'w' */
"  01111000                                           " /* 120 = 'x' */
"   01111001                                          " /* 121 = 'y' */
"    01111010                                         " /* 122 = 'z' */
"     01111011                                        " /* 123 = '{' */
"      011111RPT10                                    " /* 124 = '|' */
"       01111101                                      " /* 125 = '}' */
"        00000000                                     " /*   0 = '\0'*/
};

char phrase[41];
char correct[LINES][41] = {
  "",
  "Welcome To OOP244",
  " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@",
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`",
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{||||||||||}"
 };

int rvalues[LINES] = { 1, 18, 34, 33, 39 }, i;
int valid = 1, rc;

for(i=0; i<LINES && valid; i++) {
  rc = bit_to_ascii(core_data[i], phrase);
  if(rc != rvalues[i] || strcmp(phrase, correct[i])) {
 printf("Failed on test... %d\n\n", i+1);
 valid = 0;
  }
  else {
 printf("Passed test %d...\n\n", i+1);
  }
  printf("Your string ----------> '%s'\n", phrase);
  printf("Actual string --------> '%s'\n", correct[i]);
  printf("Your return value ----> %d\n", rc);
  printf("Actual return value --> %d\n", rvalues[i]);
  printf("Press the ENTER key to continue...");
  getchar( );
 }
 if(valid) {
  printf("\nCongratualtions!!! You passed all tests.\n");
  printf("You may hand in your assignment.\n");
 }
 else {
  printf("\nYou correctly sequenced %d/5 data blocks...\n", i-1);
  printf("Your program still needs some work!\n");
  printf("Keep at it!\n\n");
 }
 return 0;
 }

 int bit_to_ascii(const char core[ ], char data[ ]) {
   int i, rc = 0, j, inte[7], len, len2, m, rpt1, rptcounter, bin, lendata = 0, p = 0;
   char binarray[9], rpt[4], skp[9];
    rpt[4]='\0';
   for(i=0, j=0; core[i] != '\0'; i++) {
 switch(core[i]) {
 case '1':
 case '0':
  if(j<8) {
       binarray[j++] = core[i];
       binarray[j] = '\0';
    }
  else {
     binarray[j] = '\0';
     inte[0] = (binarray[0] - 48) * 128;
     inte[1] = (binarray[1] - 48) * 64;
     inte[2] = (binarray[2] - 48) * 32;
     inte[3] = (binarray[3] - 48) * 16;
     inte[4] = (binarray[4] - 48) * 8;
     inte[5] = (binarray[5] - 48) * 4;
     inte[6] = (binarray[6] - 48) * 2;
     inte[7] = (binarray[7] - 48) * 1;

     bin = inte[0] + inte[1] + inte[2] + inte[3] + inte[4] + inte[5] + inte[6] +inte[7];
     if(bin<=0 || bin >=32) {
     data[lendata] = bin;
     lendata++;
     }
     j = 0; /* resets j to 0 after 8 1's or 0's have been found */

     if(j<8) {
       binarray[j++] = core[i];
     }//end if
     }//end else
     case 'R':

    if(core[i+1] == 'P' && core[i+2] == 'T') {
      i=i+3;
      if(isdigit(core[i])) {
         rpt[0] = core[i];
         i++;

            if(isdigit(core[i])) {
               rpt[1] = core[i];
               i++;
                  if(isdigit(core[i])) {
                     rpt[2] = core[i];
                     i++;
                  }
            }

         rpt1 = atoi (rpt);
         //printf("\n\n%d\n\n", rpt1);
         len = strlen(binarray);
         for(rptcounter=0, j=0; rptcounter<rpt1; rptcounter++ ){ //loops rpt1 times
            if(len<8){
                      len2 = 8 - len;
                      m = len;
                      do {
                                  binarray[m]='0';
                                  m++;
                      }while (m != 8);
                      }
            inte[0] = (binarray[0] - 48) * 128;
            inte[1] = (binarray[1] - 48) * 64;
            inte[2] = (binarray[2] - 48) * 32;
            inte[3] = (binarray[3] - 48) * 16;
            inte[4] = (binarray[4] - 48) * 8;
            inte[5] = (binarray[5] - 48) * 4;
            inte[6] = (binarray[6] - 48) * 2;
            inte[7] = (binarray[7] - 48) * 1;
      bin = inte[0] + inte[1] + inte[2] + inte[3] + inte[4] + inte[5] + inte[6]+inte[7];
            data[lendata] = bin;
            lendata++;
         }
      }
      }
      break;
    case 'S':
   if(core[i+1] == 'K' && core[i+2] == 'P') {
   i=i+3;
   for(p=0;p!=8;i++) {
      switch(core[i]) {
      case '1':
      case '0':
           skp[p] = core[i];
           p++;
           break;
      }
   }
   }
    break;
  }//end case
  }//end for
   binarray[j] = '\0';
   len = strlen(binarray);
            if(len<8){
                      len2 = 8 - len;
                      m = len;
                      do {
                                  binarray[m]='0';
                                  m++;
                      }while (m != 8);
                      }
   inte[0] = (binarray[0] - 48) * 128;
   inte[1] = (binarray[1] - 48) * 64;
   inte[2] = (binarray[2] - 48) * 32;
   inte[3] = (binarray[3] - 48) * 16;
   inte[4] = (binarray[4] - 48) * 8;
   inte[5] = (binarray[5] - 48) * 4;
   inte[6] = (binarray[6] - 48) * 2;
   inte[7] = (binarray[7] - 48) * 1;
   bin = inte[0] + inte[1] + inte[2] + inte[3] + inte[4] + inte[5] + inte[6] + inte[7];
   data[lendata] = bin;
   lendata++;
   data[lendata]='\0';
   rc = strlen(data) + 1;
   if (rc==0) {
          rc++;
          }
   return rc;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Please read my question properly, I told that my program work fine in Code Block. But for some reason its not working on server. So maybe there is some mistakes that not giving compiler on server to compile the code properly.

Comment: There is too much code there.  You need to either cut down the code to a much simpler test case, or use the debugger to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Serjio, Oli is asking that you debug the program a little first. Why don't you log into the server where you submitted it, compile it with debugging information, execute it until it fails, then post the backtrace, core dump, and anything else that might give us more information. Then we can proceed.

Comment: Just did the debuger its says me. PROGRAM RECIEVED SIGNAL SIGSEGV.

Comment: @SerjioRamos: But it should also tell you what line that occurred on, and what the values of all the relevant variables were.

Answer (score 1):

think your problem is on line 290. lendata is to big (3533). I have some problems understanding your code. but lendata should  be less then 41 (the size of phrase)? 
(but use a debuger, on unix use gdb. there is a graphical frontend called  ddd.)
Edit:  inte is declared on line 180, to line[7]. most be line[8].

Comment: This happens also on line 202, `data[lendata] = bin;` (`lendata = 1807`).

Comment: any ideas how can I improve that?

Comment: I don't see the large `lendata`, it's always less than 40 when I print it on line 290.

Comment: think there is a problam on line 202, inte[7]. inte is decleard on line 180. to line[7]. most be line[8]

Answer (score 1):

Another problem that jumped out is

```
char binarray[9], rpt[4], skp[9];
rpt[4]='\0';
```

that you are setting `rpt[4]` to 0 although the valid indices are 0-3.

And you're writing to eight elements of `inte`,

```
inte[0] = (binarray[0] - 48) * 128;
inte[1] = (binarray[1] - 48) * 64;
inte[2] = (binarray[2] - 48) * 32;
inte[3] = (binarray[3] - 48) * 16;
inte[4] = (binarray[4] - 48) * 8;
inte[5] = (binarray[5] - 48) * 4;
inte[6] = (binarray[6] - 48) * 2;
inte[7] = (binarray[7] - 48) * 1;
```

although it is declared `int i, rc = 0, j, inte[7], ...`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm not seeing properly but shouldn't your lines in the core_data be separated by commas?

Comment: there is commas, you just dont see them. "                      00000000                       ",

Comment: Okay. Well lets look at this for a second. You have a pointer to an array. So theoretically a double array. But there is a distinction. You're using a pointer to an array but you never actually declared any space for it. Try using malloc.